# How can I implement the following excel function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Excel function ->

```
=IFERROR(MID(E14330,FIND("-0",E14330)-3,9),"None")
```

I have tried the following and it works but is very slow. I have also tried using lambda function but that didn't help either (got syntax error)

```
get_JournalData_05['PO'] = ""
    
for i, row in get_JournalData_05.iterrows():
    if get_JournalData_05['zero index'].iloc[i] == -1:
        get_JournalData_05['PO'] = 'None'
    else:
        get_JournalData_05['PO'] = get_JournalData_05['Description'].iloc[i][int(get_JournalData_05['zero index'].iloc[i] - 3):int(get_JournalData_05['zero index'].iloc[i] + 9)]
```

`get_JournalData_05['zero index']` is the column with the index I found using:

```
get_JournalData_05['zero index'] = get_JournalData_05['Description'].str.find('-0')
```

I need to fill the PO column based on extraction from the Description column.

Comment: I see you are using iterrows, which get you the index & row info as well, so you can use 
row['zero_index'] instead of get_JournalData_05['zero index'].iloc[i]
The same thing applies for every column inside the loop.
Check is this works for you.
Also you are using full index assignment : get_JournalData_05['PO'] = 'None'
This will assign the value to entire dataframe instead of just that specific row.
Use get_JournalData_05.at[i,'PO'] = 'None'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `iterrows`, look for ways to vectorize operations (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues)). In your case, we can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

**Excel**

[image: Excel]

**Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Description': ['deleteABC-01234delete', 'deleteABC-012',
                        'failABC_012fail', 'BC-012fail']}

get_JournalData_05 = pd.DataFrame(data)

get_JournalData_05['PO'] = get_JournalData_05['Description'].str.extract(r'(.{3}-.{,5})')

get_JournalData_05

             Description         PO
0  deleteABC-01234delete  ABC-01234
1          deleteABC-012    ABC-012
2        failABC_012fail        NaN  <- no `-` character found
3             BC-012fail        NaN  <- only 2 characters preceding `-`
```

For an explanation of the regular expression, see [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/KLqC7g/15). Failures to extract the pattern will lead to `NaN` values (index 2 & 3). If you insist on the *string* "None", you could chain [`.fillna('None')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using this function:

```
def extract_substring(input_string):
    try:
        index = input_string.find("-0")
        if index != -1:
            return input_string[index - 3:index + 6]
        else:
            return "None"
    except AttributeError:
        return "None"
```

This approach is way faster than iterating through each row.